# After a stalled, suspend, or waiting event are fired, how do I know when its ok to continue

Tags: html, html5-video

Its great the HTML5 video element is nice enough to let me know when it's waiting for something, but how does it let me know when its done waiting?

Answer (score 3):

Check out this link with a description of all video events with a live display of which event is happening when.
Checking `readyState` might help you.

- [HTML5 Video Events and API](http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html)

Answer (score 3):

Look out for the 'loadeddata', 'canplay' and 'canplaythrough' events - these respectively indicate that some data has been loaded, enough data has been loaded to start playback, and enough data has been loaded to start and finish playback without waiting for further buffering.